# Can't use sha1 inside class definition?

Tags: php, sha1

I'm working on a login class in PHP. I have the following line inside a class definition:

```
private $salty = sha1('salty');
```

...which is giving me the following error:

*"Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\includes\jaLogin.php on line 26"*

I've tried using this line outside of the class definition and it works fine, it's only when I use it inside the class definition that I get a problem.

If I remove the word "private" I get a slightly different error:

*Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_FUNCTION' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\includes\jaLogin.php on line 26*

I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use function-calls to initialize class member variables.

```
class YourClass
{
    private $salty;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->salty = sha1('salty');
    }
}
```

is the one way to initialize your variable.

**EDIT**

Even, e.g., a simple concatenation of two constant strings is not allowed (`protected $_string = 'Hello ' . 'World!';`). The evaluation of class properties happens at compile time, so the usage of constructs that depend on run-time information is illegal.

> [...] This declaration may include an
>   initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be
>   evaluated at compile time and must not
>   depend on run-time information in
>   order to be evaluated.

([Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php))

Comment: Bingo! Right on the mark! Thanks for that. Any idea why this is?

Comment: It's because your class is just a data structure. You always need to call a function to set them to some values.
In your case it's the constructor function.

Comment: Added some explanation. Actually it's a problem of when in the execution process the member variables are evaluated.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable as null and then initialize it in your constructor.

```
private $salty = null

function __construct() {
    $this->salty = sha1('salty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$sha1() won't function because you're trying to handle a function as a variable.

And when you're working on a better login mechanism why not start using:

```
$this->salty = hash("SHA512", "salty");
```

Additionally you can create a salt hash and add it with your password. This addition gives you a little overhead because you will have to save the salt in a db-table too and retreive and combine it when you are validation (user)credentials.

Hope it helps you!